# json replace backslash to double quote

Tags: c#

Hello guys I'm here again.
I meet a problem that is I use Web Api's **HTTP GET method** to get json data which is in my database.
The code will be:
VifundaController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
        public string Query2(string str1, string str2)
        {
            string SQL = "";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Hashtable parameters = new Hashtable();
            DBController l_dbc = new DBController("UseDB");
            DbConnection conn = l_dbc.NewConnection();
            DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

            
            SQL = ("SELECT * FROM vibfcash WHERE bfcash_year = @year and bfcash_stage = @stage");

            parameters.Add("@year", new StructureSQLParameter(str1.ToString(), SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            parameters.Add("@stage", new StructureSQLParameter(str2.ToString(), SqlDbType.NVarChar));

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = l_dbc.FillDataTable(builder.ToString(), parameters, false);

            string str_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            string js = str_json;

            return js;
        }
```

Then when I use `http://localhost/api/vifundna/Query2?str1=109&str2=2` to call api,
the api return to screen's string is with backslash and double qoutes like: `\"`
So how to replace backslash and double qoutes `\"` to only double qoutes `"` ?
Thank you guys!!! :)

Comment: const newSring = str.replaceAll('\"', '"'); should do it

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Is it possible you're double serializing the JSON, maybe try removing the SerializeObject? Just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` javascript function like this.

```
str.replace("\\", "\"");
```

If there are several `\` in the string, use loop to replacing all the `\`.

#### If you are using CSharp, do like below.

```
str = str.Replace("\\", "\"");
```

Please have a try and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Sadly, that's not working :(

Comment: Which programming language do you use? CSharp or javascript?

Comment: I use C# to programing

Comment: I've update my answer. Please have a look and try.